# How to define SWRL rule name in Protege 4?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, protege4, swrl

I utilized 'Rules' view in Protege 4

I think if protege support to define rule name.

```
Rule:        // syntax color is changed
```

I defined rule like this

```
'context data'(?data), user(?user) -> hasData(?user, ?data)
```

And I tried to define rule name.. but I didn't know how use rule name

```
Rule: 'context data'(?data), user(?user) -> hasData(?user, ?data)
```

It occurs syntax error!

How to define SWRL rule name in Protege 4?

Comment: SWRL Rules are modelled as axioms in OWL API (used by Protege). They can be annotated with labels as axioms can, but they do not have 'names' or IRIs. Old versions of OWL API (2.2.0 and 3.1, I believe) used to allow IRIs on SWRL rules, but that was incorrect and the behaviour has changed years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Does something lead you to believe that rules can be assigned names in SWRL?  I'm not aware of any such construction (but I could just be unaware of it).  There's no mention in the [SWRL abstract syntax](http://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/#2) of rules having names.

Comment: Thanks your answer.
But in Jena, a rule have name. And in protege 3, a rule have name too.
So I wonder if a rule have name and how to define in protege 4.

Comment: yes, but jena rules are a very different thing from swrl ryles. Jena rules are for rdf; swrl is for owl individuals. Swrl rules don't have names.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your intent correctly, an alternate option can be to add label to the SWRL rule using the annotation properties as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOeNB.png) (please ignore some non-standard annotation properties, which are project specific)

If I recall it correctly, Protege 3.5 supports adding names to rules, which was a fairly useful feature as it can help in isolating the desired rule from a large bank of rulesets. However, this feature is not supported in the higher versions of Protege.
Hope this helps